# Konvas.js - Chosse background by click class css

Tags: javascript, jquery, konvajs

I'm trying, using Konvas.js, to click on imgback class and change the background according to the clicked image:

https://jsfiddle.net/hk7xe0we/3/

I do not want to put an id on each image

Following code:

Jquery:

```
$('.back').click(function(){
    imgback = $('img').attr('src'); 
});
```

Html

```
<h2>Background</h2> 
    <span class="back"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://lorempixel.com/450/400/animals" width="50px"></span>
     <span class="back"><img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/city" width="50px" ></span>
```

Thanks for any help

https://github.com/EditorsJS/editorimagekonvajs

Comment: whats wrong with the code in your previous question?

Comment: The previous question has been settled, I found most organized create a new topic

Comment: fair enough - looks like some of the code in that question answers this one though

Comment: trying to click on any image background, but always stays the same background https://jsfiddle.net/hk7xe0we/3/.  so does the image item                       https://jsfiddle.net/hk7xe0we/5/ Background and image item together It is confusing https://jsfiddle.net/hk7xe0we/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use this statement

```
imgback = $('img').attr('src');
```

it gets the first img's src from the html. Instead of doing that, you should get the image from the clicked 'back' element. Which should be:

```
 imgback = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
```

I have forked your jsfiddle and updated it. https://jsfiddle.net/1t0qz1rx/2/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not a problem, @Zeli :)